# Custom unicode on already created object

Tags: django, django-queryset, choicefield

I'm using permissions in my application. And in some case I need to create form only with permission field. I'm using ModelChoiceField and queryset with permission objects.

```
permission = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Permission.objects.all())
```

But permissions unicode is taking too much place in choice field. And it looks not so good. I want to use in my choice field only permission's name. Is it possible?

Comment: I solved it! Just using simple ChoiceField and create own choices to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [proxy model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#id8), and override the `__unicode__()` method on that.

Comment: Thanks! Useful information, but I'm decided to use `ChoiceField` and write choices with permission's id and permission's name. Working :)